# Rspec: Allow double to receive message across multiple tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I just made an update to my code that broke the below test and 50 others with the below error:

```
#<Double AnonymousEvent> received unexpected message :provider with (no args)
```

I was able to fix one by adding `allow(anon_event).to receive(:provider)` in the body of the `it` block (see code below), however this obviously doesn't fix all of them.

Is there a way allow the `anon_event` double to receive `:provider` when it's defined. Or add a before_action kind of thing?

**One of the many tests**

```
RSpec.describe Something::Parser::AnonymousParser do
  subject { described_class }
  let(:anon_event) { double(AnonymousEvent, provider_data: provider_data) }
  let(:provider_data) { { 'description' => agenda } }

  it { is_expected.to be }

  describe '.applicable?' do
    subject { described_class.applicable?(anon_event) }

    context 'invalid' do
      let(:agenda) { 'Not valid' }

      it 'returns nil' do 
        allow(anon_event).to receive(:provider)  # FIX HERE
        expect(subject).not_to be
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can define it in a before block before the `describe '.applicable?' do` line

```
before do
  allow(anon_event).to receive(:provider)  # FIX HERE
end
```

Comment: @MattHough glad to be of help, can you accept the answer?

Comment: Yes sorry there was a time limit before I could accept it.